# how to populate a dropdown with h2 tags and change html content, depending on the h2 clicked by the user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://boxes.site44.com/

I have these boxes, and when a user clicks book in any of them, the clicked box will expand and will appear a form.

Now i am trying to populate the dropdown on the left upper side (you have to click on book to see) with the h2 tags (which box have the h2 title tag) and change the content, depending on the h2 clicked by the user.

The HTML is very large, because of that i made a fiddle:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/62Lw4bjz/

The to expand the box is:

```
var $expander = $('.event .cta');
var $actual = $();
var $others = $();
var $clicked = $();


$expander.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $clicked = $(this);
    $clicked.addClass('hidden');
    $actual = $(this).closest('.event');
    $others = $('.event').not($actual);
    $others.addClass('hidden');
    $actual.find('.event__info-list').addClass('inline');
    $actual.find('h2')
      .addClass('event__close')
      .append('<span class="event__arrow" aria-hidden="true">&#9660;</span>');
    $actual.find('.expanded').slideDown().css('display', 'flex');


    $("html").velocity("scroll", { offset: $("#sell").offset().top, mobileHA: false });

    $actual.velocity('transition.expandForm', {
        delay: 0,
        duration: 800,
        ease: 'easeOutSine'
    });
});
```

---

All the dropdowns that i saw, works with lists `(<li>)`, it is possible populate the dropdown with the h2s title tags from each box, or i need change the html in order to make it work?

- How to change the box based on the clicked `h2`?
- Is there example code to help me with this?
- Should I use jquery's `change` to achieve this?

I am open to suggestions, i am stuck on this for 3 days..

Thanks very much.

---

Update:

[image]

This is not a dropdown when the box expand, but i need to bee a dropdown that has options to navigate to the other boxes.

Comment: Where are the `H2 title tags` exactly in your code?

Comment: Third time this is posted and still no clear idea of .. where the dropdown is or where the h2 tags are and exactly what you are expecting from this. You just aren't explaining it well

Comment: In the JS fiddle the h2 title tags is the 'Something', in the boxes.site44.com is the 'Something' and 'Something2'. @Mouser

Comment: Ok. Located them. What needs to be in it?

Comment: Just a sec, @charlietfl.. i will update the question

Comment: I do not understand why you do not understand the question. You are looking at the JS FIDDLE? I cant be clearer than that.

Comment: I had a pretty hard time decoding your message. Had to use my dev tools to go through your fiddle.

Comment: I am obviously not the only one. After all you have posted this several times before. I even suggested you scale the demo down to it's simplest form which didn't seem to happen. You may know this widget inside out...we don't

Comment: obvius you are the only one.. Mouser help me :)

Comment: downvote my post will not work, i have friends here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/62Lw4bjz/4/

Edited your jQuery `find` in your `$expander.click` function. This will append a list to the `h2` element. Hide it using CSS and displays/hides it when the user clicks on the menu. In a very basic way this will do it:

```
    $actual.find('h2')
      .addClass('event__close')
      .append('<span class="event__arrow" aria-hidden="true">&#9660;</span>')
      .append('<ul class="dropdown hidden"><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li></ul>')
      .click(function(){
            if ($(this).attr("data-expanded") == true)
            {
                $(this).find("ul").toggleClass('hidden');
                $(this).attr("data-expanded", false);
            }
          else
          {
                $(this).find("ul").toggleClass('hidden');
                $(this).attr("data-expanded", true);
          }
      });
```

CSS:

```
ul.dropdown {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.6);
    z-index: 1000;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul.dropdown.hidden {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;

}

ul.dropdown > li:hover {
  background-color: #FFCC99;
}
```

jQuery `append` also accepts a function as input. So you can dynamically build the HTML string with other book options.

What you need to do yourself:

- Attach click handlers to the list items.
- Change the list items to the box references you want them to be.
- Handle the hiding of the menu when your box is collapsed.

Comment: Thanks Mouser, this is not my area, i work in the backend. If u are interesting, i can give u a bound of 100 points for all the answer.